# Hover table rows but still keep background color of some cells

Tags: html, css, hover

Some cells on my table have background colors. The table's row colors are alternating. I created a hover in table row. When the mouse is over a row, it hovers and all the background colors of some colorful cells are invisible. How can I hover but still keep the background colors of cells when the mouse pointer is over the row. My codes for hover and alternate colors:

CSS:

```
tr:hover td,
tr.even:hover td.active,
tr.odd:hover td.active {
background-color: #EBEBEB ;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#dfe7f2");        
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in plain css.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
```